# Transform a matrix of lists into a data.frame

Tags: r, dataframe, matrix

I need to transform a (large) matrix of lists into a data frame.

Example:

```
m <-matrix(list(c(1,1,1),c(2,2),c("a","a","a"),c("b","c")), nrow = 2, ncol = 2)
> m
     [,1]      [,2]       
[1,] Numeric,3 Character,3
[2,] Numeric,2 Character,2
```

Desiderata:

```
test <- data.frame(x=c(1,1,1,2,2),
                   y=c("a","a","a","b","c"))
> test
  x y
1 1 a
2 1 a
3 1 a
4 2 b
5 2 c
```

Answer (score 0):

The elements are `list`.  We may `unlist` by looping over the columns with `apply` and `unlist` the `list` elements

```
type.convert(as.data.frame(apply(m, 2, unlist)), as.is = TRUE)
```

-output

```
   V1 V2
1  1  a
2  1  a
3  1  a
4  2  b
5  2  c
```

---

Or instead of `apply` (which returns a `matrix` and matrix can only have a single type - characters have precedence over numeric type, thus the whole matrix is `character` and therefore we used `type.convert` to automatically convert the type), split by col (`asplit`), loop over with the columns with `lapply`, `unlist` and convert to `data.frame`

```
data.frame(setNames(lapply(asplit(m, 2), unlist), c("x", "y")))
  x y
1 1 a
2 1 a
3 1 a
4 2 b
5 2 c
```